# Number of possible combinations involving the digits 1-9 (inclusive)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here's the problem (per a Sudoku puzzle).

Suppose I want to know the total number of combinations (order is **NOT** important) using ANY of the digits from 1-9 (inclusive) and WITHOUT repetition.  Furthermore the sum total of the digits and the number of digits in the combination are a Given.  The sum of the digits  must equal the stated sum

For example:
Sum = 10;
Number of Digits = 2;
Number of combinations = **4** (must be the solved value).

Listing as follows: (9,1); (8,2); (7,3); and (6,4).  Two digit combo's are easy to calculate manually, which is what I did here.

Now assume:
Sum = 17;
Num of Digits = 3;
Num of Combo's = 8 (again determined manually - and I might have missed one or two!).

For example:(3,6,8); (3,5,9); (4,6,7); etc.
A number cannot repeat in a grouping, but can repeat in another grouping - as does the digit 3 in the first two listed groups.

So, is there a way to solve for the number of possible combinations with the two Givens and stated condition as indicated??

Someone please say: "Yes, here's how".

joey

Comment: Ill have to go through it  but it looks good  -  and very professional too!!

Comment: J.    Did you try the formula on my examples.  Use the sum of 17 and three digits.  If I didn't miss anything, the result should be 8.   thanks

Comment: Look at the $x^3q^{17}$ term of [the expansion of $\prod\limits_{j=1}^9(1+xq^j)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+Product+from+j%3D1+to+9+of+%281%2Bxq%5Ej%29) and read the coefficient.  It should have been $7$ outcomes, not $8$, so you must have made an error.

Comment: Ok  thanks  Yes, I counted

Comment: Yes!!I counted (3,6,8) and (8,6,3) as two separate combinations